# PHP Xpath Error already defined in Entity not showing results

Tags: php, xpath

I am getting errors in this php xpath app and i cannot fix, i would love some help if possible

```
 <?php
   //Get Username
    $username = $_GET["u"];

    $html = file_get_contents('http://us.playstation.com/publictrophy/index.htm?onlinename='     .$username);
    $html = tidy_repair_string($html);
    $doc = new DomDocument();
    $doc->loadHtml($html);
    $xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
    // Now query the document:
        foreach ($xpath->query('//*[@id="id-handle"]') as $node) {
        echo $node, "\n";
        }
        foreach ($xpath->query('//*[@id="leveltext"]') as $node1) {
        echo $node1, "\n";
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `@` before `$dom->loadHTML($html)` because loadHTML usually rises a lot of warnings and notices

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
```

Comment: that has seemed to remove the errors but nothing is showing in the nodes, any ideas?